# How to avoid the "loaded.created.uncommitted" error when doing unloadAll with ember-data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My application creates a lot of "configuration" models (ie- they only live in the app at runtime and they won't ever be persisted). I load these on demand so my app is constantly creating records and then throwing them away.

```
//create a record that will never be persisted
this.store.createRecord('foo', {name: 'wat'});
```

In the past I would just do a clear of the store but I realized this doesn't actually "remove" anything. I've decided to use the unloadAll instead

```
this.store.unloadAll('foo');
```

... but I run into this error as I have these "configuration" models

> Error while loading route: Error: Attempted to handle event
>   `unloadRecord` on  while in state
>   root.loaded.created.uncommitted. 
>       at new Error (native)

How can I avoid this error (while still using the unloadAll as I need to truly remove these from the browser) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this has now (should be) fixed with my PR which was merged 2 days ago:

see: https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1714

That PR loosens the constraint which disallowed unloading all dirty records, to disallowing only inFlight records. I believe with some time and proper thought, that constraint may also be lifted.

The rest of the PR, is specifically around proper cleanup when unloading a model, a record array, or destroying the store. I do believe this is a good first pass at proper cleanup.

I hope this (merged) PR solves your issue, if not please open a descriptive issue, and lets squash the bug.

Comment: Awesome! I'm not on master but I was able to adapt based on the PR (thanks a million)